# Rails: How to store extra attributes using single table inheritance?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I'm building an application in Ruby on Rails, Rails 4.

Let's say I have a table `Users` and I want to specify two types of users `User_1` and `User_2`

`User_1` will use all of the columns from the parent table `Users`, but `User_2` will use all of the columns from the `User` table like `User_1` but need two extra columns to hold details. The question is where and how are these extra details stored?

Are they columns added to the parent table `Users`? or are the extra attributes coded in the `Model` or `Controller`? I'm looking to store two pieces of integer data, which they will input in their profile.

Thanks for taking a look! :)

Comment: I'd only normally use STI where the models had the same attributes but required different behaviour. If you find a distinction between the various attributes required it may be better to go for two tables and models.

Comment: If the **only** difference is that User_2 has extra attributes, then just keep it in one model. Separating the models using STI will only make sense if the two types of users have methods with the same name but behave differently.

Comment: I believe Roob is correct in this instance. The two users will have slightly different behaviour and features on the application, on top of that just the additional attributes. Thank you both very much for your input.

Comment: I would hope the "single table" would be a give-away, as to where to find or place the attributes) :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single Table Inheritance basically means that all subclasses of `User` are sharing a single database table, in your case `users`. Since you need to store the data in the database, you need to add additional columns to your `users` table.

You can find [more information on STI in the Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance).

Comment: Fantastic! Just to check, I'm guessing it would make sense to hold the all `User_1` values under this attribute/column as null? Thanks FiveDigit! :)

Comment: Yes you'd need to make sure the columns can have null (or some sensible default) to prevent database errors when saving instances of `User_1`.

Comment: STI makes most sense if there is at least some overlap in attributes and functionality. If they are completely disjoint, I would consider other options: separate models, mixin shared behaviour and use polymorphic links.

Answer (score 0):

Extra attributes are all stored in the parent table `User`. Behind STI scene, there is just one table in your database with an attribute `type` telling rails which model should be used. If you want an inherited model to have some columns, it must be set in your parent model, ie. in your database.

Extra attributes are stored in the database, and your model is rails way to help you accessing it.

Comment: So to define the differences between `Users` I also have to store a `String` value `Type` in the `User` table?

Comment: Yes your base table `users` will need a column named `type` of type string that will hold the name of inherited model (`User_1` or `User_2` in your example) to retrieve them. Take a look at the doc mentioned by @fivedigit.

Answer (score 0):

It seams you're in need for the mentioned [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance).
But before you proceed I really recommend you to check more information about them. Check this [blog post](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/) for a more theoretical explanation and how and when to use it.

For a more complete example check [this example](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2220311&seqNum=4).

If you still have a pro acount on railscast, [there's one about](http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations?view=comments) it.